# как отправить подтверждающий звонок при авторизации телеграмм

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon, pyrogram

У меня есть номер телефона, с которого мне нужно авторизоваться, для авторизации мне нужно использовать звонок, а не сообщения.

Я пробовал делать следующее:

```
from pyrogram.raw.functions.auth import SendCode
from pyrogram.raw.types import CodeSettings

phone = "12022177028"
api_id = 2382333
api_hash = "3121cc5e4a42121470161f1c1558a321"

res = SendCode(
    phone_number=phone,
    api_id=api_id,
    api_hash=api_hash,
    settings=CodeSettings(
        allow_flashcall=True,
        current_number=True,
        allow_app_hash=False
    )
)
```

в переменной res я получаю следующий вывод:

```
{
    "_": "functions.auth.SendCode",
    "phone_number": "12022177028",
    "api_id": 2382333,
    "api_hash": "3121cc5e4a42121470161f1c1558a321",
    "settings": {
        "_": "types.CodeSettings",
        "allow_flashcall": true,
        "current_number": true,
        "allow_app_hash": false
    }
}
```

Из документации по pyrogram я понял, что мы можем отправить подтверждение с помощью метода send_code, но он принимает только номер телефона, и нет способа передать словарь, который я получаю из SendCode.

В итоге возник вопрос, как можно подтвердить вход не через СМС, а через звонок при входе в аккаунт Telegram?

Если вы можете предоставить пример в других фреймворках Python или в telethon, я буду вам очень благодарен!

Comment: о каком списке речь? В чем проблема передать из полученного словаря только телефон?

Comment: Это позволит отправить смс, а нужно после этого ещё и отправить звонок для подтверждения.